# Wordpress crop image

Tags: wordpress

Не получается разобраться с жёсткой обрезкой изображения в wordpress.
Использую

```
add_image_size( 'service-thumb', 500, 200, true );
```

и вывожу изображение

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail("service-thumb"); ?>
```

Но изображение всё равно не обрезается жёстко, а подгоняется по одной стороне.

> true (жесткое кадрирование) 
>   Если установить четвертый параметр в true, то миниатюра будет
>   уменьшена и обрезана точно под указанные размеры

Ощущение что параметр crop не работает. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может нужно перегенрить изображения?
[Regenerate Thumbnails](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Я просто задавал новые изображения для постов, которые уже были на сайте...

Comment: @korg, пжл, сам когда-то с таким "повозился".